# MonoMac and Launch Services

Tags: monomac

I'm a .NET Developer trying my hand at an application on OS X.  MonoMac makes so many things easy for me.  I've managed to write an application useful to myself using just the MonoMac posts people have done and the Apple Developer documentation.

I can't seem to find out how to actually associate a file extension to my application.  I believe this needs to be done via Launch Services or maybe add something to the Info.plist in my project.

Any hints, code or how tos?

Answer (score 1):

Read this guidelines on Runtime Configuration from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/000-Introduction/introduction.html as pointed by this answer: [How to associate a specified type of file with my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313652/how-to-associate-a-specified-type-of-file-with-my-program/313698#313698)